# Pattern for check single occurrency into preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm writing a function that should retrieve all occurrences that I pass.
I'm italian so I think that I could be more clear with an example.
I would check if my phrase contains some fruits.

Ok, so lets see my php code:

```
$pattern='<apple|orange|pear|lemon|Goji berry>i';
$phrase="I will buy an apple to do an applepie!";

preg_match_all($pattern,$phrase,$match);
```

the result will be an array with "apple" and "applepie".

How can I search only exact occurency? 
Reading the manual I found:
http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php

I try to use `\A` , `\Z` , `^` and `$` but no one seems to work correctly in my case!

Someone can help me?

EDIT: After the @cris85 's answer I try to improve my question ...
My really pattern contains over 200 occorrency and the phrase is over 10000 caracters so the real case is too large to insert here.

After some trials I found an error on the occurrency "microsoft exchange"! There is some special caracters that I must escape?
At the moment I escape "+" "-" "." "?" "$" and "*".

Comment: `Goji berry` is very expensive.

Comment: But `preg_match_all` finds all matches. Why not use `preg_match`?

Comment: You need to use word boundaries `\b`, put them around each word or put your alternation in a group and put the `\b` around the group.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte  : really? sincerly I don't know what it is :-) I inserted that fruit because from wikipedia is the first fruit formed from 2 word :-D

Comment: @ u_mulder  : I don't know very well preg libs, but you are right!

Comment: @cris85 thanks for your example but it doesn't work :-)

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte : are you speacking something like: $pattern='<(\b(apple)|\b(orange)|\b(pear)|\b(lemon)|\b(Goji berry)>i'; ?

Comment: @Filippo1980: You can do `<\bapple\b|\borange\b...` or like @chris85 (shorter and more efficient).

Comment: Sorry @cris85 your code seems work correctly! I didn't write?: ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anchors you tried to use are for the full string, not per word. You can use [`word boundaries`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to match individual words. This should allow you to find only complete fruit matches:

```
$pattern='<\b(?:apple|orange|pear|lemon|Goji berry)\b>i';
```

The `?:` is so you don't make an additional capture group, it is a `non-capture group`.

Here's the definitation from regex-expressions for what a boundary matches:

> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

PHP Demo: https://3v4l.org/h5GCf

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/5aBaMO/1/

Comment: There is a little bug .. It didn't find the last fruit: "Goji berry"!

Comment: Can you post your string? Seems to find it here, https://regex101.com/r/5aBaMO/2/.

Comment: @cris85 : yesterday I saw the error into "Microsoft exchange", today, after some tests, I saw the problem wasn't  on "two words" but in this specific case! I modify my question but, perhaps, I should create a new one... however I accept your answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: So `$pattern` is dynamic, not static? `Microsoft exchange` doesn't have any special characters. You could use `preg_quote` if you have some other words that are breaking the expression.

Comment: Yes the phrase is dinamic! How I found this example that doesn't work correctly:

Comment: $pattern="<\b(?:microsoft|Java|Oracle database|Apache|Microsoft Exchange)\b>i";
$part="I know Java and I worked also on Oracle database using Oracle ADF and Microsoft Exchange";

Comment: The result? Java, Oracle Database and Microsoft! Should it return also Microsoft Exchange right?

Comment: The single `microsoft` matches first, put the exchange first, or add the exchange there and make it optional. `\b(?:microsoft(?: exchange)?|Java|Oracle database|Apache)\b`