# Which is more efficient between str_pos and preg_match?

Tags: php, performance, preg-match-all, strpos

After this question:
[Pattern for check single occurrency into preg_match_all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814916/pattern-for-check-single-occurrency-into-preg-match-all)

I understand that my pattern must contain only a word per cycle because, in the case reported in that question, I must find "microsoft" and "microsoft exchange" and I can't modify my regexp because these two possibilities are given dinamically from a database!

So my question is: which is the better solution between over 200 preg_match and the same numbers of str_pos to check if a subset of char contains these words?

I'm trying to write the possible code for both solution:

```
$array= array(200+ values);
foreach ($array as $word)
{
    $pattern='<\b(?:'.$word.')\b>i';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
    $fields['skill'][] = $matches[0][0];
}
```

the alternative is:

```
$array= array(200+ values);
foreach ($array as $word)
{
    if(str_pos($word, $text)>-1)
    {
    fields['skill'][] = $word;
    }
}
```

Comment: REGEX based functions are slowers than most other string functions. By the way your test can also do it with one regex if you do it like `$pattern='<\b(?:'.$word1.'|'.$word2.'|'.$word3.'|'.$word4.')\b>i';` and how many words you can use at once depends on how long the regex can be. I have created at test regex that was 12004 chars long. Seems not the max.

Comment: `str_pos()` is generally 3-20x faster than preg_match because preg_match is mainly used to probe the format of a string, and to retrieve sections of it based on regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos` is much more fast than `preg_match`, here is a benchmark:

```
$array = array();
for($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) $array[] = $i;
$nbloop = 10000;
$text = <<<EOD
I understand that my pattern must contain only a word per cycle because, in the case reported in that question, I must find "microsoft" and "microsoft exchange" and I can't modify my regexp because these two possibilities are given dinamically from a database!

So my question is: which is the better solution between over 200 preg_match and the same numbers of str_pos to check if a subset of char contains these words?
EOD;

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<$nbloop; $i++) {
    foreach ($array as $word) {
        $pattern='<\b(?:'.$word.')\b>i';
        if (preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches)) {
            $fields['skill'][] = $matches[0][0];
        }
    }
}
echo "Elapse regex: ", microtime(true)-$start,"\n";


$start = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<$nbloop; $i++) {
    foreach ($array as $word) {
        if(strpos($word, $text)>-1) {
            $fields['skill'][] = $word;
        }
    }
}
echo "Elapse strpos: ", microtime(true)-$start,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
Elapse regex: 7.9924139976501
Elapse strpos: 0.62015008926392
```

It's about 13 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

> REGEX based functions are slowers than most other string functions.

By the way your test can also do it with one regex if you do it like `$pattern='<\b(?:'.$word1.'|'.$word2.'|'.$word3.'|'.$word4.')‌​\b>i';` and how many words you can use at once depends on how long the regex can be. I have created at test regex that was 12004 chars long. Seems not the max.

The regex version (single call):

```
$array= array(200+ values);

$pattern='<\b(?:'.implode('|',$array).')\b>i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
//$fields['skill'][] = $matches[0][0];
```

strpos version (multi calls)

```
$array= array(200+ values);
foreach ($array as $word){
 if(strpos($word, $text)!==false)//not with >-1 wont work.
 {
   fields['skill'][] = $word;
 }
}
```

If you looking for single words, strpos will match `Hello` in `HelloWorld`,
so if you only want real sepreated words, you can do:

```
$arrayOfWords = explode(' ',$string);
//and now you can check array aginst array 
$array= array(200+ values);
foreach ($array as $word){
 if(in_array($word,$arrayOfWords))//not with >-1 wont work.
 {
   fields['skill'][] = $word;
 }
}
//you can makes this also faster if you array_flip the arrayOfWords 
//and then check with 'isset' (more faster than 'in_array')
```

That you also want to match word combinations ("microsoft exchange") can not be done in this way, if you not have this combinations in your word list.

*added comments

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however your regexp have aproblem ... as I said, if I'm looking for "Microsoft" and "microsoft exchange" in the same phrase your solution will find only one result!

Comment: @Filippo1980 OK, but the checked answer will also not get "microsoft exchange" only if you look for "microsoft exchange" not "microsoft" alone, an my answer was more pointing to _what is faster_. And _my regexp_ is the same as _your regexp_ only whit looking for more than one word at once ;-) And your question was really about preformance not about the results you want. --> _So my question is:..._